# PHP - Checking for return false;

Tags: php

Just a quick question - and I'm sure really basic!

I have the following code:

```
function checkThings($foo, $bar) {
    ...
    if ($valid) {
        return $results;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On the other end of this I am currently doing

```
$check = checkThings($foo, $bar);
if ($check === false) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo $check;
}
```

Is writing the following the same?

```
$check = checkThings($foo, $bar);
if (!$check) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo $check;
}
```

Which method is the preferred method if both are correct?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The triple-equal operator is type-sensitive.  So when you check:

```
if ($check === false)
```

... it will only be true if `$check` is the boolean value "false".  Wheras

```
if ($check == false)
```

... is not checking specifically for boolean false, but a "falsey" value.  False, in PHP, equals zero, null is "falsey", as is an empty string (`"" == false == null`, but `"" !== false !== null`).  So:

```
$check = 0;
if ($check == false)
```

... evaluates to true.

The `!` prefix operator is equivalent to `==`.  So when zero needs to be a discrete value from boolean false, the `!` and `==` operators are not sufficient.

Check out the docs for comparison operators here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

It is best practice to make your conditional checks as specific as possible.  This is not only to avoid potential oversights in your logic, but also to make the code more maintainable for future developers.  Imagine encountering a line of code like this:

```
if (check_something($variable)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

I can assume the `check_something` function is returning a boolean value true.  But, unless I go dig up the `check_something` function, it **could** also be returning an non-empty string, a number... who knows!  Much more clear to do this:

```
if (check_something($variable) === true) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Now, just by looking, I know that the `check_something` function is ***expected*** to return a true value.  I might not know what the function does, but at least it is exactly clear what it returns.  Another common example you see EVERYWHERE:

```
if (!$_GET['value']) {
  // do something
}
```

This is a pet peeve.  A conditional statement should always be comparing things clearly.  So, you'd want to do:

```
if (array_key_exists('value', $_GET) !== false && $_GET['value'] === '1') {
  // do something
}
```

Now, you can tell that I am not only checking to see if the query string parameter exists, but also whether it is equal to a specific value.

In summary, the single `!` prefix operator and the `==` operator are rarely useful and always ambiguous.  You're best served by writing your code in a way that documents itself, or is translatable into human language to express the logic at play.  A direct comparison using either `!==` or `===`, where appropriate, is a good habit, good practice, and the least likely to produce unexpected results in your code.

Comment: BTW, this is a problem specific to `php` (and perhaps other loosely typed languages), due to its extreme willingness to automatically convert values from one type to another.  In strongly typed languages (e.g. Java, C#, C++),  most programmers prefer concise syntax such as `!value` ("not value") instead of `value == false` or `value === false`.  In those languages, the compiler will complain if `value` is not a Boolean type, so the concise form is safe. `"not value"` has a clear meaning, both in logic and in human language; it is only the "looseness" of `php` that makes this form poor to use.

Comment: ^ and javascript to an extent

Comment: takes tonns of time to find it so deep in code

Answer (score 7):

=== false checks type, (!$check) evaluates the value and will fail for values returned such as null, '' (empty string) and zero(0)

=== is most correct

Answer (score 4):

They are similar, but not exactly the same. The `!$check` is a loose checker, meaning `0` and `null` would evaluate to true as well. The `===` is a strict checker, meaning it must be `false`.

For a more indepth explanation: [PHP Types Comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 1):

There is a case where the use of the single `!` prefix operator would not involve any risk and it is when the type of the expression to evaluate is always a boolean.

For example, the expression below

```php
if (!is_array($var)) {
```

will always behave similarly to

```php
if (is_array($var) === false) {
```

This is because the function [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) always returns a bool as result.

```php
is_array ( mixed $var ) : bool
```

Some people may find easier to read the first expression with the single `!` prefix operator. The only thing to have in mind when using this is that when used with expressions where the returned type is mixed we may have unexpected results as other comments already pointed.

Answer (score 0):

== does a value comparison where === does a bitwise.

```
// will return true only when $value = false
if( $value === false )

// will return true when $value = 0, $value = "", $value = null, etc
if( $value == false )
if( !$value )
```

Comment: `===` compares value and type of the 2 things.  It's not `bitwise`.

Comment: It's the first time I heard about `bitwise` regarding the === operator. More info could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer your second method, but put the positive check first (if($check) instead).

Comment: This would fail for the same reasons as using `!$check`.  He really should use `$check !== FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check for multiple conditions, you can do this:

```
function checkThings($foo, $bar)
{
    else if ($valid === false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ($valid === 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ($valid === 2)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if ($valid === 3)
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

But you must strictly check the return of the function with "===" when you are attempting to check which value is returned and what piece of code ran.

Answer (score 0):

in my case when I ve got a value from JS Datatable I checked it as:

```
if($value=='true'){ // or for 'false' }
```